# Cluster point, accumulation point once again.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

I'm taking two different math's courses simultaneously.

While in the first one we had defined an accumulation point c in a set $A$ as a point in which:

$c$ is a cluster point if $\forall$ open reduced ball around $c$ $\cap$ $A \ne \emptyset$

The second one defined an cluster point (which I understand is the same as accumulation point)of a $\{x_n\}^{\infty}_n$  as

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ and\  \forall N, \exists \ n\  such \ that\ x_n $ belongs to the open ball of c with $\epsilon \  radius$

After that the second course used the first definition as definition of limit (or cluster) point of a set (I know that they're not the same, but that is what the book says).

I'm truly in a lost. Can someone shed light into this matter? Are both definitions equivalent or it depends on the lecturer and the book?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a reduced ball?

Comment: If the book claims that they are equivalent definitions, it would be a good exercise to attempt to prove them equivalent, or to find an example of a sequence $x_n$ and point $c$ where $c$ is a cluster point of $x_n$ but not an accumulation point of $x_n$ (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are working with metric spaces, as opposed to general topological spaces, as your language suggests as much.

One issue is that there is a notion of a cluster point for a set and a cluster point for a sequence. Note that your first definition is for what it means to say $c$ is a cluster point of a set $A$. The second definition is what it means to say $c$ is a cluster point of the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$. There is an error in your second definition. It should read: $c$ is a cluster point of a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0\ \forall N \in \mathbb{N}\ \exists n \geq N : x_n \in B_\epsilon(c)$, where $B_\epsilon(c) := \{y \in X \mid d(y,c)< \epsilon\}$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$. This is the same as saying for any open ball $B$ around $c$ there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $x_n \in B$.

These are two distinct notions of a cluster point. They are closely related but not the same.

Comment: I think his second definition might be that of a limit point of a set; i.e. a point $c$ for which there exists a sequence $(x_n) \in A$ which converges to $p$ (equivalently, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ s.t. $n \geq N \Rightarrow x_n \in B_{\epsilon}(p)$). Could it be that he’s asking about the difference between a limit point of a set and a cluster point of a set?

Comment: Thank you @Keefer, I didn't realize there were two different types of accumulation points, one for sets and one for sequences.However, the first one (the first definition) is a cluster point iff there is a convergence sequences towards it's.Therefore I suspect both definitions are related, aren't they?